# css: responsive style of iframe tag with @media query not working

Tags: html, css

If I resize the browser window, the width and height of iframe tag remain unchanged.
how to fix this?

```
@media (max-width:700px){.video-container2{
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}.video-container2 iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}}
```

```
<div style="display: flex; padding: 8px; width: 100%">
    
    <div class="video-container2">
        <iframe frameborder="1" width="400px" height="255px"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kBcLgP4WJ4I"></iframe>
    </div>
    
    <div style="padding-left: 8px; width: 49.99%;">
        <h5 style="margin-top: -8px;">hwgh hwhwfhwlfhw lgw lh wlh lwfwf</h5>
        <p style="margin-top: -8px; font-size: 10px;">Channel name</p>
        <p style="margin-top: -12px; font-size: 8px;">101 views.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you added this meta tag to the head tag?<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0">

Comment: yes, i added that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get rid of the default width and height like so.

```
<div class="video-container2">
        <iframe frameborder="1" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kBcLgP4WJ4I"></iframe>
</div>
```

and declare it purely with css.